# Select and inner join with condition

Tags: abap, opensql

I would like to get customer address (street) from one table (kna1) when customer partner role is "WE" in other table (vbpa).

I've done it like this however it returns completely different address from wrong customer. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT SINGLE stras
FROM kna1
INNER JOIN vbpa ON (vbpa-kunnr)
WHERE parvw EQ 'WE'
INTO @zadrwe.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your inner join is not correct.

Answer (score 6):

Your inner Join is not correct.You can use below code to see correct value.

```
DATA zadrwe TYPE stras_gp.

SELECT SINGLE stras
FROM kna1
INNER JOIN vbpa ON kna1~kunnr = vbpa~kunnr   
WHERE parvw EQ 'WE'
INTO @zadrwe.
```

Comment: thank you, but this is giving different stras value, but still not the correct one. maybe would be worth to mention tables and columns: table kna1 column kunnr, stras, table vbpa column kunnr, parvw

Comment: For correct result, you have use full key of table vbpa where as you are using only parvw. Full key should be base on Sales and Distribution Document Number
Item number of the SD document
Partner Function

Comment: @kasper, Umar presented you a valid syntax now your initial query makes no sense without a selection which makes the result a unique line because you do a SELECT SINGLE which takes only the first line. For instance, better do: `SELECT SINGLE ... WHERE vbpa~vbeln = 'yoursalesorder' AND vbpa~parvw = 'WE' ...`